# Code Editor with intellisense for ANTLR4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, sharpdevelop, code-editor, nrefactory

Looking for sample for building ANTLR4 grammar based Code Editor with intellisense. SharpDevelop provides all Code Editor features, however if we need to provide the intellisense and Code Completion details, then we need to write own parser.

Need sample where ANTLR4, SharpDevelop is used for building the Code Editor for custom language.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the expected Tokens from ANTLR4 using GetExpectedTokensWithinRule API in the Listener and converting them to tokens.

pseudo code looks like this

```
public class MyGrammarListener : MyGrammarBaseListener
{
       public MyGrammarListener(MyGrammarParser parser)
        {
             this.Parser = parser;
        }

        public override void EnterXXXXX(XXXXX_Context context)
        {
            IntervalSet set = Parser.GetExpectedTokensWithinCurrentRule();
            base.EnterXXXXX(context);
            foreach (int token in set.ToIntegerList())
            {
               // Returns the expected tokens.
               string data = Parser.Vocabulary.GetLiteralName(token);
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have used Jide CodeEditor with antlr4, it seems to be working OK but took some time to get it together. I generate the errors and keywords for highlighting from the parser. I use listeners for parsing etc. and a visitor for executing the language. Not familiar with SharpDevelop

Comment: ps antlr4 supports Java, not so sure about other languages. In my work I generate code folding from the antlr listeners too.

Comment: Thank You for the quick answer. I am looking on option on how to achieve CodeCompletion using ANTLR.